# Magento1.9 Out of Stock Products in Search Results

Tags: magento-1.9, php, search

One of my customers wants to search for products which are out of stock.

Is this somehow possible without using any search extension like elastic search or something like that?

Maybe with a modification of the Magento search?

Comment: hello @dbachmann without any extension or modification of the Magento search just set Display Out of Stock Products to yes in configuration then it will also display out of stock product in search result

Comment: @chandreshchauhan A modification wouldn't be the problem. Out of stock products appear in the category view but not in the search results. So, the question is how do I modify the search to show out of stpck products in the results.